# How to make `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` clip to the view border during rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I add a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` pretty much based on Apple's documentation about [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/index.html) as the following:

```
 AVCaptureSession *captureSession = <#Get a capture session#>;<br>
 AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:captureSession];<br>
 UIView *aView = <#The view in which to present the layer#>;<br>
 previewLayer.frame = aView.bounds; // Assume you want the preview layer to fill the view.<br>
 [aView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
```

I added the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` function in order to handle the rotation with the following code:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
    [self.videoPreviewLayer setFrame:self.view.layer.bounds];
    [self.videoPreviewLayer.connection setVideoOrientation:[self getAVCaptureVideoOrientation]];
}

- (AVCaptureVideoOrientation)getAVCaptureVideoOrientation {
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if ( deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft )
        return AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
    else if 
        // and other 3 orientations
        // ...
}
```

The result looks okay but but animation not so good. The camera layer doesn't start resizing until the rotation finished and I can see the background view during the rotation.

http://yzhong.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/My_Movie_1_-_Small.gif

Then I start looking around and found these two SO questions: [Problems automatically resizing AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer on rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641330/problems-automatically-resizing-avcapturevideopreviewlayer-on-rotation.) and [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer smooth orientation rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016963/avcapturevideopreviewlayer-smooth-orientation-rotation). I tried the solutions proposed in those question and added the following function:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (_videoPreviewLayer) {
        if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
            [self.videoPreviewLayer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0)];
        } else if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
            [self.videoPreviewLayer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2)];
        } else if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
            [self.videoPreviewLayer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2)];
        } else {
            [self.videoPreviewLayer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI)];
        }
        self.videoPreviewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    }
}
```

And I get this following, which is a lot better. However, the animation is still a little weird. It seems like it is rotating backward and then forward to the right position? Now I have no clue what to do next.

http://yzhong.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/My_Movie_2_-_Small.gif

What I am looking for is really very simple. I want to have a nice, smooth and natural transition/rotation such as the Apple's default camera app does. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

http://yzhong.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/My_Movie_3_-_Small.gif

Please help!

Comment: You will probably need to disable the orientation changes allow which you can per app, via  the plist or per ViewController by overriding the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method. Then use the standard iOS facilities to detect the gyroscopic motion programmatically and explicitly rotate the view in real time, based on the current realtime orientation of the device. Since you're trying to achieve a very particular customization, that is not what the vast majority of users need, you have to take more responsibility for handling the details of it.

Comment: instead of starting the rotation in the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: method, couldn't you use the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: to adjust the view before the animation takes place?